# MarkLogic: Unusual type of log in MarkLogic error log file?

Tags: nosql, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm noticing some unusual type of log in MarkLogic error log file.

[image]

```
Thread: ACCESS_VIOLATION
#  1 0x0000000141830859 in xdmp::Tokenizer::operator++() (tokenizer.cpp:1599)
#  2 0x0000000140c605b4 in xdmp::RetokenizedAtomIterator::init() (datamodel.cpp:1494)
#  3 0x00000001405d0f83 in xdmp::FieldValueAtomIterator<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::firstNode()
(searchbuiltins.cpp:2700)
#  4 0x00000001405d1b23 in xdmp::FieldValueAtomIterator<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::nextNode()
(searchbuiltins.cpp:2790)
#  5 0x00000001405d1c31 in xdmp::FieldValueAtomIterator<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::operator++()
(searchbuiltins.cpp:2583)
#  6 0x0000000140652e38 in xdmp::FieldValueAtomIterator<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::getChars()
(searchbuiltins.cpp:2811)
#  7 0x000000014100ceff in xdmp::StandardIndexerEnv<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::getFieldChars()
(indexer.cpp:3044)
#  8 0x00000001410140b0 in xdmp::StandardIndexerEnv<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::putFieldRangeIndex()
(indexer.cpp:3056)
#  9 0x000000014103ac49 in xdmp::IndexerWalker<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::walkElemNodeEnd()
(indexer.cpp:11045)
# 10 0x000000014103f22d in xdmp::StandardIndexerEnv<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::pop()
(indexer.cpp:11642)
# 11 0x0000000141040027 in xdmp::IndexerWalker<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::walk()
(indexer.cpp:11833)
# 12 0x00000001410438e9 in xdmp::StandardIndexerEnv<xdmp::SwitchingAtomIterator>::putNode()
(indexer.cpp:2068)
# 13 0x00000001410468b2 in xdmp::StandardIndexerPostingData::putNode() (indexer.cpp:12300)
# 14 0x00000001418ade9b in xdmp::UpdatePath::fragmentInsert() (updatepath.cpp:335)
# 15 0x0000000140763208 in xdmp::refragment() (updatebuiltins.cpp:13237)
# 16 0x0000000140763505 in xdmp::refragment() (updatebuiltins.cpp:13319)
# 17 0x0000000140e24422 in xdmp::ForestReindexerThread::refragmentDocuments() (forest.cpp:22298)
# 18 0x0000000140e290da in xdmp::ForestReindexerThread::run() (forest.cpp:2628)
# 19 0x0000000141b18032 in svc::Thread::top() (thread.cpp:386)
# 20 0x0000000141b18279 in runThread() (thread.cpp:423)
# 21 0x0000000141d05453 in _callthreadstartex() (threadex.c:348)
# 22 0x0000000141d05507 in _threadstartex() (threadex.c:326)
```

It would be great if anyone can help me to fix this.

Comment: That is a so-called stacktrace, due to a core dump. Very uncommon, but they do occur. Upgrade to latest patch release if you aren't yet, and inform support as MarkLogic is keen to hear about cases like this.

Comment: Have you overwrite the default tokenization of the MarkLogic?

Comment: @grtjn: This occurred when we tried to create a field range index for a field for which we made some entries for special characters under "tokenizer overrides" and it happened for a larger database only, on a smaller database it is working smoothly, not really sure but looks like a data issue.

Comment: yes @NavinRawat, we tokenized some punctuations [. / - _ :] for a field and then tried to create a field range index for the same field.

Comment: Or it is hitting an internal limit of some kind. Tokenizer stuff is fairly new. Did you reach out to support yet?